# How to create an ego graph with Pandas Dataframe in networks?

Tags: python, data-visualization, networkx

| BaseRate | DepartmentName | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | Production | Vice President |
| 140 | Executive | CEO |
| 30 | Maintenance | Engineer |
| 70 | Production | Assistant |

```
D = nx.ego_graph(B, n = 'CEO')
nx.draw(D,node_color=color, 
                with_labels=True, 
                node_size=1500,
                arrowsize=20)
```

I want CEO node in the center and the DepartmentName nodes to be connected to it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your example I only get a graph with two nodes. Hence, I created a different example with more nodes, but created the position of the nodes, which you were looking for using the `circular_layout`

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

edges = [("P", "CEO"), ("E", "CEO"), ("M", "CEO"), ("D", "CEO")]

B = nx.Graph()
B.add_edges_from(edges)

nodes_without_ceo = list(B.nodes)
nodes_without_ceo.remove("CEO")
pos = nx.circular_layout(nodes_without_ceo, center=(0, 0))
pos["CEO"] = (0, 0)
print(pos)
nx.draw(B,
        pos=pos,
        # node_color=color,
        with_labels=True,
        node_size=1500,
        arrowsize=20)

pl.show()
```